# How do I deploy a Xamarin Forms iOS app to iPhone test device offsite

Tags: ios, testing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app and I would like to distribute the iOS version to our tester, but the tester is not local, so I have no physical access to their iPhone device. I would like to do this remotely somehow.

I have searched for instructions on this, but all I find are deployments to the App Store or deployments to a physical device attached to my mac (which I have done fine).  Can anyone advise the process of deploying this to our remote working tester please?

Thanks

Comment: use a distribution service like TestFlight or AppCenter.ms

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll have a look at AppCenter.ms

Comment: You could have a try with AppCenter and have a look at this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading